Why does gcc compare seemingly equal floating point values as different with "-fexcess-precision=standard"?
Look at this snippet:
int main() {
    double v = 1.1;
    return v == 1.1;
}

On 32-bit compilations, this program returns 0, if -fexcess-precision=standard is specified. Without it, the program returns 1.
Why is there a difference? Looking at the assembly code (godbolt), it seems that with -fexcess-precision=standard, gcc uses 1.1 as a long double constant (it loads the constant as TBYTE). Why does it do so?
First I thought it was bug, but I found this gcc bug comment, it seems that this behavior is intentional, or at least it is not unexpected.
Is this a QoI issue? I understand that the comparison is executed using long double precision, but still, my 1.1 is not a long double literal. The weird thing is that if I cast the 1.1 at the comparison to double (which is already a double), the issue goes away.
(Another weird thing is that GCC does the load and compare twice, see the double fucomip instructions. But it does this even in 64-bit mode. I understand that in my godbolt link, optimization is turned off, but still, there is only one comparison in my code, why does GCC compare twice?)
Here's the asm code, without -fexcess-precision=standard:
main:
        push    ebp
        mov     ebp, esp
        and     esp, -8
        sub     esp, 16
        fld     QWORD PTR .LC0
        fstp    QWORD PTR [esp+8]
        fld     QWORD PTR [esp+8]
        fld     QWORD PTR .LC0
        fucomip st, st(1)
        fstp    st(0)
        setnp   al
        mov     edx, 0
        fld     QWORD PTR [esp+8]
        fld     QWORD PTR .LC0
        fucomip st, st(1)
        fstp    st(0)
        cmovne  eax, edx
        movzx   eax, al
        leave
        ret
.LC0:
        .long   -1717986918
        .long   1072798105

And here is with it:
main:
        push    ebp
        mov     ebp, esp
        and     esp, -8
        sub     esp, 16
        fld     QWORD PTR .LC0
        fstp    QWORD PTR [esp+8]
        fld     QWORD PTR [esp+8]
        fld     TBYTE PTR .LC1
        fucomip st, st(1)
        setnp   al
        mov     edx, 0
        fld     TBYTE PTR .LC1
        fucomip st, st(1)
        fstp    st(0)
        cmovne  eax, edx
        movzx   eax, al
        leave
        ret
.LC0:
        .long   -1717986918
        .long   1072798105
.LC1:
        .long   -858993459
        .long   -1932735284
        .long   16383


Is that extend floating-point for 64 bts doubles as 80 bits doing operations? Comparing two 80 bits registers with 64bits values (even one identical value) would fail equality? That would be terrible.

First, the value 1.1 can not be exactly represented in the IEEE-754 standard.  Assuming an Intel-compatible processor, your program is testing whether this number with 64 bits of precision equals the same number with 80 bits of precision.

Compilers are allowed to do floating-point calculations at more than the precision of the types used in the calculation. That's because Intel hardware, unless you so something truly perverse (hello, Java), does its calculations with 80 bits of precision. When you store a value it has to be reduced to the precision appropriate for the type it's stored in. So double v = 1.1; will store 1.1 as a double, typically 64 bits. But in v == 1.1 the 1.1 can be 80 bits, and v will be extended to match; because v has been truncated, they're typically not equal.

What do you get if you use long double v = 1.1?

@catnip -- how is long double defined? Not a rhetorical question; Microsoft originally implemented long double as an Intel 80-bit floating-point type, but when they got cross-platform religion they changed it to 64 bits.

@PeteBecker Good question.  Probably depends on your tool chain

@catnip -- yup.

@PeteBecker: 1.1 is not the result of some computation, it is a double literal. Ideally, this literal should represent the closest double value to 1.1. And then when this double is converted to long double, it will compare equal to v (because during conversion, the value didn't change). But here gcc invents new binary digits to 1.1, to make it equal 1.1L. If I wanted to have that, I'd have written 1.1L.

@geza: 1.1 is a string of characters. To produce a double from it, the computer has to do things. That is a computation. So the resulting double is the result of a computation. People do not think about that much, but it is work the computer does, and it is part of C semantics. The C standard has some statements about it, and they are pretty lax. Particularly relevant here is this passage in C 2024 6.4.5.3: “The values of floating constants may be represented in greater range and precision than that required
by the type…” So converting 1.1 to a long double value is conforming.

@EricPostpischil I just read a similar paragraph in the C++23 standard:  "The values of the floating-point operands and the results of floating-point expressions may be represented in greater precision and range than that required by the type; the types are not changed thereby" - So, the literal 1.1 operand may in fact be represented as a long double. What surprises me is that it's not truncated when compared to a double (since its type is not changed which would promote the value of v to long double  in the comparison) but it seems gcc promotes v's value to long double anyway.

@TedLyngmo: Thanks, I missed the C++ tag. The C++ standard does not have the same wording as the C standard about literals/constants specifically, just that statement about “operands.”

@EricPostpischil Cheers! I was trying to write up an answer but then I got stuck on this promotion idea. Perhaps a mind-trap. I'll get some sleep and see what nice answers that may have come in when I wake up instead :-)

@geza Research FLT_EVAL_METHOD.  Please report the output of printf("FLT_EVAL_METHOD %d\n", FLT_EVAL_METHOD);

@chux: it is 2.

@geza IIRC, As 2, that allows the 1.1 in v == 1.1 to be converted from code to a long double and so not equal to the v as that contains a coarser double version of 1.1.  Curious what does printf("%a %a %La %d\n", v, 1.1, (long double) 1.1, v == 1.1); do on your machine?

@chux: 0x1.199999999999ap+0 0x1.199999999999ap+0 0x8.cccccccccccdp-3 1 and 0x1.199999999999ap+0 0x1.199999999999ap+0 0x8.ccccccccccccccdp-3 0. The value of (long double)1.1 differs for the -fexcess-precision=standard version, it has 12 more bits in the mantissa.

@geza - Under the 2 cases, what was FLT_EVAL_METHOD for each? 2 for both?

@PeteBecker: Just for the record, GCC's default is -mlong-double-80 (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Options.html#index-mlong-double-64-1). Definitely for Linux, and IIRC also when targeting Windows, surprisingly not ABI-compatible with MSVC. sizeof(long double) == 12 (for 32-bit) due to the i386 SysV ABI using alignof(long double) == 4.  (x86-64 uses alignof(long double) == 16 so it's padded up to 16 bytes).

@chux: yes, 2 for both. But this makes sense, as FLT_EVAL_METHOD is about operations other than assignment and cast, and -fexcess-precision is about assignment/cast (at least, according to the doc, it controls whether it is allowed that assignment/cast doesn't drop excess precision).

@geza As I see the C spec (and I assume applies to C++), treating code 1.1 as the value  0x8.ccccccccccccccdp-3 and not the shorter 0x8.ccccccccccc-3 is not compliant.  If valued as a long double value, we lose rounding control which sometimes affects things.

@geza Consider adding link to post -fexcess-precision=style or something like that.

@chux: if GCC makes sure that the excess-precision value, when rounded to double, is a value which equals to the original value of the literal, then I suppose things are fine. But I'm not sure that GCC does this. I wouldn't be surprised if GCC just used the closest long double value to the literal, which in rare circumstances doesn't round to the closest double value.

@geza  I think this example suffices: double x = 9000000000000001.499999; ( a value just under 2^53.)  If 9000000000000001.499999 is parsed as a double, x gets the value of 9000000000000001.0 - the nearest double.  If 9000000000000001.499999 is parsed as a long double, x gets the value of 9000000000000002.0 since code 9000000000000001.499999L rounds to 9000000000000001.5L and that converted to a double is 9000000000000002.0.  So by using a wider type for the constant than coded, we have a less correct value for x due to two roundings.

@chux: thanks for doing the hard for work on this! I created an godbolt example, which shows that the value gets rounded incorrectly: https://godbolt.org/z/sv3EaoEKE. I think I will report this to gcc's devs.

https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=118016

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

In C, it is permitted (as indicated via FLT_EVAL_METHOD) that a floating point literal may hold a value with more prevision as permitted by its type and that at the same time floating point operators are evaluated in a higher precision than the operand types permit as well.
In that case v == 1.1 can be false because the literal 1.1, although of type double, will not be rounded to double precision, but == still compares it in higher precision against the stored value of v which still must be rounded to a value representable by double.
In C++, although it is still permitted for floating point operations to be evaluated in higher precision, the value of a floating point literal still needs to be rounded to a value representable in its type.
However, this interacts incorrectly with specification incorporated from C, such as FLT_EVAL_METHOD, and deviates from C for seemingly no reason, so the question of precision of floating point literal values is still an open issue, see https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2752.html and https://github.com/cplusplus/papers/issues/1584.
Without the -fexcess-precision=standard flag GCC doesn't behave standard-conforming at all and may even interpret the value of v as higher precision than its type permits, which is not permitted by either C or C++ standard. (Assignment, casting and initialization should always force a rounding to a value representable value in the actual type.) With that it can happen that v == 1.1 is true again by virtue of both the literal and the value of v as retrieved from the literal never being rounded to a representable double value.
All of this is typically relevant on e.g. a 32bit x86 compilation, where FLT_EVAL_METHOD will often be defined as 2, meaning that the higher precision mentioned above should always be chosen as if the type was long double. This is to support keeping double as 64bit type while performing floating point operations in 80bit precision on the x87 FPU. Normally this choice for FLT_EVAL_METHOD makes the behavior deterministic in the sense that it is possible to tell exactly where a rounding is applied, but note that GCC's default (-fexcess-precision=fast) will not be consistent in whether and where rounding will be applied at all.
Given that FLT_EVAL_METHOD is 2 and given the choices for floating point types, following the C rules, v == 1.1 evaluating to false is the only correct standard-conforming behavior. For C++ that is different, but it isn't clear whether that is a defect in the C++ standard. It is therefore somewhat understandable why GCC would follow the behavior required in C.
The fact that v == 1.1 can evaluate to false is very intentional and programmers need to be aware of the excess precision behavior, unless they make sure that their code only needs to support implementations with FLT_EVAL_METHOD == 0 where no excess precision will be applied.

@chux Yes, terminology is a bit different. I'll assume that your comment is enough clarification for a reader.

user17732522, Sorry.  my (now deleted) comment was based on the incorrect thought that this was a C question.

For Intel processors, long double is often an 80 bit floating-point type, larger than plain double at 64 bits.
And then it makes sense: You take 1.1 with 80 bit precision, round down to 64 bit precision, and store in a double.
Then you take 1.1 with 80 bit precision and compare it to 1.1 with 64 bit precision. Values are different because one has 16 bit more.

Specifically, if my calculations are correct, 1.1 in double precision is 0x1.199999999999a, while in 80 bits (with 64 bits of precision) it's 0x1.199999999999999a.
